# Numerals in font are not aligned properly

Tags: windows, macos, fonts

Please pay attention to font's numerals. As you see, the digits have different heights and vertical alignments. The thing is, I downloaded this font from multiple sources. All of fonts are displaying like that on Mac OS X, Windows etc.

But in fact there is written text using this font, which looks correct. When I copy and paste this text, it shows properly again. But when I type text using keyboard, it displays like on screenshot.

What might be problem?

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a problem with the font itself. You should get in contact with the maker of the font. It might very well be by design.

Answer (score 2):

[Typotheque](https://www.typotheque.com/) is the foundry that produced [Fedra Sans](https://www.typotheque.com/fonts/fedra_sans), so that is the best source of information.

Fedra Sans' [numerals page](https://www.typotheque.com/site/fonts.php?tn=about&id=1&page_id=10) makes it clear that the default numeral style uses [Old-style Figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_style_numbers), so the "different padding from the top" is indeed by design. Sounds like you are expecting the more conventional modern/lining/titling figures. (That aforelinked Wikipedia page does a nice job of explaining the rationale and use of each figure type.)

Good news: Typotheque was nice enough to include alternative numeral styles in the font via OpenType features. Bad news: Accessing said features is limited to [applications that support them](https://www.typotheque.com/fonts/opentype_feature_support). Butterick's Practical Typography has a [good explanation of the situation](http://practicaltypography.com/opentype-features.html).